# Frameworks have generic folder icons

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, icon

I just noticed this recently so I'm not sure whether it started being like that after installing Catalina or some time later.

I’ve installed Xcode version 11.2.1 from the App Store and some of the icons for frameworks that get installedlook like generic folders instead of having the "Lego" brick icon in Finder.

[image]

This is quite annoying as it makes it harder to tell them apart from regular folders. How can I change it back?

Comment: Can you post the get info window in finder or one specific folder?

Comment: @bmike https://imgur.com/a/byfiB2n

Comment: Not sure why you didn’t edit that in the post - but hopefully I got things correct - feel free to edit the main body so it’s correct. Good info - since it’s not a system framework, my hunch is irrelevant. This might just be something Apple changed in that app - let’s see what others think.

Comment: Wasn't sure whether this was actually relevant. But just to be clear: The framework in the screenshot is just an example. The issue affects all frameworks no matter if it's from the System or one I built.

Comment: This is a perfect example - it shows that it’s not a system change?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have seen this before. Years ago. Went away when I reinstalled the OS some time later.